# Electron app communication with backend fails

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, electron, capacitor

I have an existing project with a Java backend and an Angular frontend. I would like this app to be available as a desktop application as well, so I am trying to use Electron to package the application.

I've managed to create a desktop app that includes the frontend, but no data from the backend is shown. Since the frontend and backend communicate via HTTP requests I expected the Electron app to be able to get data as usual (as long as the backend is running obviously).

When I start the app with `ng serve` or `ionic serve` everything works as expected, but with `npm run electron:start`, the requests to the backend fail.

My folder structure looks something like this:

```
|-- app
|-- data
|-- web
|  |-- electron
|  |   |-- capacitor.config.ts
|  |   |-- package.json
|  |-- src
|  |-- package.json
|  |-- angular.json
|  |-- capacitor.config.ts
|  |-- ionic.config.ts
```

In /web/package.json the electron scripts are defined like this:

```json
"electron:install": "cd electron && npm install && cd ..",
"electron:prepare": "npm run remove:sql:wasm && ng build && npx cap sync @capacitor-community/electron && npx cap copy @capacitor-community/electron",
"electron:start": "npm run electron:prepare && cd electron && npm run electron:start",
"electron:make": "npm run electron:prepare && cd electron && npm run electron:make"
```

In /web/electron/package.json these are the scripts

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "electron:start-live": "node ./live-runner.js",
    "electron:start": "npm run build && electron --inspect=5858 ./",
    "electron:pack": "npm run build && electron-builder build --dir -c ./electron-builder.config.json",
    "electron:make": "npm run build && electron-builder build -c ./electron-builder.config.json -p always"
  }
```

When I open the developer tools in the electron app (Ctrl+Shift+I) I see errors in the console:

```
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>…, 
text: '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>\n  <meta char…203c0.js" type="module">\x3C/script>\n\n</body></html>'}
headers: G {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for capacitor-electron://-/api/user"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "capacitor-electron://-/api/user"
```

Is there a problem with the URL? When I go to `http://localhost:8080/api/user`, I get the expected response: `{"id":1,"shortName":"test1","salutation":null,"title":null,"firstName":"Test","lastName":"User","roles":[]}`

I have no idea how to go about debugging this, I have very little experience with Electron (and web development in general). Does anyone know what exactly the problem is, or how I could go about finding the problem (and fixing it)?